# Passing preferential command line flags to combined scripts in nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line, flags

I have a combination script in nodejs `package.json` file, for example

```
"scripts": {
    "combination": "node service1.js; node service2.js"
}
```

I can run this combination script using

```
$ npm run combination
```

This command will run `service1.js` first and when the execution of `service1.js` is terminated, `service2.js` will start. Both of these scripts can accept same command line optional flags. For example,

```
node service1.js --showlog=true --logintodatabase=true
node service1.js --showlog=true --logintodatabase=true
```

However, I want to pass these command line flags only to `service1.js` when running the `combination` script. If I execute the `combination` script by providing command line flags as

```
$ npm run combination -- --showlog=true --logintodatabase=true
```

the flags apply to `script2.js`.

How can I pass the command line flags to `combination` script so that the flags are received only by `script1.js` and not by `script2.js`. I need to preserve the order of execution of scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by splitting the `combination` script into `combination` and `postcombination`, i.e.

```
"scripts": {
    "combination": "node service1.js",
    "postcombination": "node service2.js"
}
```

Now when I run

```
$ npm run combination -- --showlog=true --logintodatabase=true
```

First the `service1.js` script receives the flags and executes, and then `script2.js` executes.